# which mime type can I use for .MSG file using FILE object

Tags: angular, mime-types, msg

I have tried to get MIME-type from the FILE which is uploaded earlier but, it is return ''. Is there any library or code for getting file-type of the outlook files in Angular. ex: **for images it is showing 'images/png'**. please have a look. for **.msg** file extension **outlook** file it is showing

[image]

But for **.png** file, it is showing **file type** as below

[image]

in this [site](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File/type])

they mentioned **Uncommon file extensions would return an empty string** 
How to overcome this issue??? Please help me out to get the MIME type as application/vnd.ms-outlook
application/octet-stream.

Comment: Are you asking what the MIME type should be, or how to determine it programmatically?

Comment: "I have tried to…": Then provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 3):

I came across the same issue/problem that the browser doesn't return correct mime-type for outlook-msg-files. Instead of `application/vnd.ms-outlook` the type-property of `File` shows an **empty string**.

I used the following workaround (by checking the file-extension) to overcome this problem:

In my file-upload-logic, I test the dragged or selected file(s) if they are from any or more accepted mime-types. If there is a file without given mime-type, then I check the file-extension.

Further validation logic, e.g. if the given file is really of outlook-message-type, can be done on the server-side with your prefered programming language.

```ts
    let enableOutlookMimetypeDetection: boolean = true;

    let acceptRegexString: string = "(image/png)|(application/vnd.ms-outlook)"; // maybe you have to escape the slashes in the regex
    let allowOutlookMsgFiles: boolean = enableOutlookMimetypeDetection && acceptRegexString.indexOf("application/vnd.ms-outlook") >= 0;

    let acceptRegex: RegExp = new RegExp(acceptRegexString);
    for (let i: number = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        if (allowOutlookMsgFiles) {
            if (files[i].name !== null && files[i].name !== undefined && files[i].name.endsWith(".msg")) {
                console.log("outlook msg-file found");
                continue;
            }
        }

        if (!acceptRegex.test(files[i].type)) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I deal with 'mail' type files saved from outlook with '.msg' format. You can't change type on a file directly, so you need to make a 'copy' of it and than set a MIME of 'application/vnd.ms-outlook'. Feel free to add more type checks or 'else' cases.

```js
  onHandleFileInput(event: any): void {
    if (event?.target as HTMLInputElement & EventTarget) {
      const f = event?.target?.files[0];

      if (f.type === '' && f.name.endsWith('.msg')) {
        const mailFile = new File([f], f.name, { type: 'application/vnd.ms-outlook' });
        this.uploadFile(mailFile);
      } 
    }
  }
```

Comment: does this happen only with msg files? are there other exceptions that we should consider?