# What do you do when AngularJS FileUploader returns nothing for file type?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, outlook, mime-types

I have a web file uploader program. I use AngularJS FileUploader to pre-process the files before sending them to the backend. Works file for zip and text files for example. I test for the file type and reject if not one of those. But now that I need to add support for MS Outlook .msg files I am running into a problem. When I output file.type to the console on a .msg file it is blank. So of course when I test for application/vnd.ms-outlook it fails.

Cannot find a solution online. Most want to know what the mime type is to check against but if AngularJS is reporting null then there is no need to test it with a mime type.

```
angular.module('myApp')
    .controller('UploadController', function($location,$rootScope,$scope,$state,FileUploader){
   $scope.$state=$state;
   $scope.error_msg = null;

   var myupload = $scope.uploader = new FileUploader({
       url:"rest/api/myupload"
   });

   myupload.filters.push({
      name:'fileTypeFilter',
      fn: function(item,options) (
      console.log('The file type is'+item.type);
```

I just want item.type to get the file's mimetype so I can test for it in a if/else statement.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check file MIME type with javascript before upload?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18299806/how-to-check-file-mime-type-with-javascript-before-upload)

Comment: But like i said it is blank . . . it shows nothing when I print out the type. The question is now what? What do I do now?

Comment: What is the `FileUpLoader` service? Is it your own custom service. Or is it a third-party library?

Comment: https://github.com/nervgh/angular-file-upload

Comment: here is a solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55687631/which-mime-type-can-i-use-for-msg-file-using-file-object