# Download .msg using fetch in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, fetch, msg

I'm building an application using Angular 10. I have a function that downloads files from a local server. This function works fine for extensions - **`.PDF, .xlsx, etc.`** , except files with **`.msg`** extension. On download, it returns a file of size 0KB.

[image: .msg files]

This is my function:

```
downloadFile(url:string,fileName:string){
  fetch(url)
  .then(res => res.blob())
  .then(blob => {
    
    var a = document.createElement("a");
    document.body.appendChild(a);
    a.style.display = "none";

    var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);

    a.href = url;
    a.download = fileName;
    a.click();
    window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
  });
}
```

I tried to use these headers but still, it didn't work:

```
application/octet-stream

application/download
```

How do I resolve this problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [which mime type can I use for .MSG file using FILE object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55687631/which-mime-type-can-i-use-for-msg-file-using-file-object)

Comment: Interestingly, I found that dupe by searching for "mime type for .msg file"....

Comment: @HereticMonkey Where do I put the mime type in the fetch request?

Comment: In the `Content-Type` header.

Answer (score 0):

Use `application/vsd.ms-outlook` as MIME type for .msg extension.